# My site is asking for authentication username and password

Tags: authentication

Myt site [Hoodtrends](http://hoodtrends.com.ng) is requesting for Authentication username and password. Please can someone help me out with this?
[image]

Comment: Go to your backend services and fix the site. Avoid the login, as it can cause by hacked backend configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a normal wordpress authentication dialogue, but rather a server-level permission request.  There is probably an issue with folder permissions or a mis-configuration with your cPanel.  Your hosting company can probably clean this issue up for you.

Also, is your domain actually https://hoodtrends.com.ng/ and not https://hoodtrends.com or https://hoodtrends.ng?  Often times people will do things like .com.ng to make a credible looking evil twin site to try to steal credentials.  If hoodtrends.com.ng is not your actual domain, then it is possible that your site was compromised and redirected to an evil twin site so that the hacker could then use your admin credentials to steal data from your actual website.

Comment: My domain is http://hoodtrends.com.ng and http://hoodtrends.com is also redirecting to http://hoodtrends.com.ng

Comment: I have contacted my host but they are yet to reply my mail.